# Working on vue2 to vue3 migration, found the problem ‘’Unexpected token 'export'‘’

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-cli

During my migration from vue2 to vue3, while running the application, I found an error line in the `node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/build/setPublicPath.js` file, which reads  `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'` The content of the error file reads

```js
/* eslint-disable no-var */
// This file is imported into lib/wc client bundles.

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  var currentScript = window.document.currentScript
  if (process.env.NEED_CURRENTSCRIPT_POLYFILL) {
    var getCurrentScript = require('@soda/get-current-script')
    currentScript = getCurrentScript()

    // for backward compatibility, because previously we directly included the polyfill
    if (!('currentScript' in document)) {
      Object.defineProperty(document, 'currentScript', { get: getCurrentScript })
    }
  }

  var src = currentScript && currentScript.src.match(/(.+\/)[^/]+\.js(\?.*)?$/)
  if (src) {
    __webpack_public_path__ = src[1] // eslint-disable-line
  }
}

// Indicate to webpack that this file can be concatenated
export default null
```

I'd like to solve the problem without modifying the code in this file, as I'm sharing the code with others, so I'm trying not to modify the code in the `node_modules` directory

Comment: Have you checked the "Related questions" listed below?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . What exactly is the migration? Please, list all the steps. It could be the problem with build tool (vue cli), which the file belongs to, not vue itself. "found an error line" - found where? Please, list full error and explain under which condition it happens.

Comment: You would probably have better luck with Github Issues for Vue. https://github.com/vuejs